# MIN & MAX In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
slno    Date        In          Out        Hours      
---------------------------------------------------
  1     2015-08-17   5:32 PM    9:32 PM    04:00:00 
  2     2015-08-17  10:33 PM   12:00 AM    01:27:00 
  3     2015-08-18   5:31 PM    9:00 PM    03:29:00 
  4     2015-08-18  10:00 PM   12:01 AM    02:01:00
```

I need the result like this

```
slno    Date          In          Out        Hours    
-----------------------------------------------------
 1      2015-08-17    5:32 PM     12:00 AM   05:27:00     
 2      2015-08-18    5:31 PM     12:01 AM   05:30:00
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: what are you having problems with?  You haven't really shown any effort here.  How does your derived result come out to slno 1 and 2, is slno just a sequence?  I would have expected it to be potentially 3.  What happens if hours surpass 24 hours? does it keep going up?  does it reset to 00:00:00?  Don't leave anything up to assumptions if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
select row_number() over (order by date), X.in, X.out, convert(time, out - in)
from (
  select date, min(in) as in, max(out) as out
  from yourtable
  group by date
) X
```

Didn't test this so it might not be 100% accurate, but you should get the idea.